# Reversing a singly linked list in python... I think I'm misunderstanding how python deals with references

Tags: python, reference, linked-list

I was just trying what I though would be a rather simple problem, but in coding it up I seem to have come across some difficulties. Below is the code... The function 'my_reverse' is how I coded it up, and I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work (although I'm sure the mistake is rather simple). The function 'reverse' is some code I found online, which does work. It seems that our methods are very similar. Also, within the while loop, when you set nxt = current.nxt, then set current.nxt = last, doesn't that make nxt.nxt = last?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, nxt):
        self.val = val
        self.nxt = nxt

def my_reverse(n):
    if (n.nxt is None):
        return n
    prev = n
    curr = n.nxt
    while (curr is not None):
        nxt = curr.nxt
        curr.nxt = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = nxt
    return prev


def reverse(n):
    last = None
    current = n
    while (current is not None):
        nxt = current.nxt
        current.nxt = last
        last = current
        current = nxt
    return last

def traverse(n):
    iter = n
    while iter != None:
        print iter.val
        iter = iter.nxt

n0 = Node(4, None)
n1 = Node(3, n0)
n2 = Node(2, n1)
n3 = Node(1, n2)

traverse(n3)

l = my_reverse(n3)
traverse(l)
```

Comment: *when you set `nxt = current.nxt`, then set `current.nxt = last`, doesn't that make `nxt.nxt = last`?*. No, because you *rebind* `current.nxt`. `nxt` doesn't follow that rebinding.

Comment: I see. So is there an exception with lists? Because I know if you set a = [1, 2], then set b = a, then do b.append(3), a will now be [1, 2, 3]. Are there any other exceptions?

Comment: That is something different altogether. Then you are copying across a reference to the same object and altering the object itself. But if you then do `b = c`, then `a` doesn't suddenly point to `c` as well.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is good except you have forgotten to terminate the linked list.

Change:

```
prev = n
curr = n.nxt
```

to

```
prev = n
curr = n.nxt
n.nxt = None
```

and it works.